Python + Selenium で Edge を起動したい
PythonでEdgeを起動したいと思い、ChatGPTを使用しつつ下記コードを書きました。
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver_path = r'C:\Users\ユーザー名\edgedriver_win64\msedgedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=driver_path)

driver.get('https://www.google.com')

ただ下記エラーが発生してしまい進まないです。
どこに原因があるかさっぱりわかりません。
ValueError: Timeout value connect was <object object at 0x00000167CAB98920>, but it must be an int, float or None.

selenium=3.141
Edgeバージョン 125.0.2535.79 (公式ビルド) (64 ビット)
WEBDriverも上と揃えているつもりです。
お手数お掛けしますが、宜しくお願い致します。

seleniumの版数が古すぎるのでは？ 現在は 4.21.0 で 3.141 は2018年11月1日リリースですよ。 リリース履歴

WebDriverを使用してMicrosoft Edgeを自動化する場合、Selenium 4を使用する必要があります。Selenium 3はサポートされていません。ChatGPTのような生成AIアシスタントは平気で嘘をつきまくるので、ファクトチェックを怠る人には向いていません。まず公式リファレンスを参照してください。Use WebDriver to automate Microsoft Edge - Microsoft Edge Developer documentation | Microsoft Learn / WebDriver を使用して Microsoft Edge を自動化する - Microsoft Edge Developer documentation | Microsoft Learn (日本語のページのほうは低品質の機械翻訳なので、参考程度にとどめてください)

該当の説明をピンポイントで示すとここですね。Selenium 3 はサポートされていません

皆様、ご回答頂き本当にありがとうございます、
そして無知で大変申し訳ございません。ご教示ください。
!pip install selenium==4.21.0
にてseleniumのバージョンを上げようとした際に
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
msedge-selenium-tools 3.141.4 requires selenium==3.141, but you have selenium 4.21.0 which is incompatible.
このようなエラーメッセージが返ってきます。こちらはどのように対処すればよいでしょうか、、？

pipを最新にしてから作業してみてはどうでしょう？ ［Python］pipのアップデートの仕方

ご回答頂きありがとうございます。
頂いた内容、試させて頂きます。
大変助かりました。

msedge-selenium-toolsを使用されていますか？こちらは現在非推奨となっているのでアンインストールした方が良いかと思います。（https://pypi.org/project/msedge-selenium-tools/） そうすればSeleniumのコンフリクトも解消されるのでは？

質問には書いていないけれど msedge-selenium-tools を import しているというなら import を外せばよいでしょうし、import していなくても install されていれば自動的に使われてしまうというのなら uninstall する必要があるでしょう。先に紹介した Selenium 3 はサポートされていません の記事の直後に Microsoft Edge 用 Selenium Tools が使用されなくなりました と記載されています。Selenium 4 には、Microsoft Edge 用の Selenium Tools は必要ありません。 Microsoft Edge 用の Selenium Tools は Selenium 3 専用でした。
